# Sharekit+Cocos2d Facebook Image share screen not positioned correctly in landscape mode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sharekit

I am using sharekit with a cocos2d application (app is throughout landscape), I am getting no error, but the share screen that comes up, is in portrait mode, covering roughly 1/3 of the screen. Keyboard which pops up is in Landscape mode (as expected). Only "cancel" button is visible.

The Code:

```
self.vc =[[ViewController alloc] init];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:self.vc.view];
[[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:vc];

[[SHK currentHelper] setCurrentView:vc];

SHKItem *item;
item  = [SHKItem text:@"I HATE MOSQUITOS"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Library Verison :
ShareKit 2.0

Extra Info :

I tried using SHKMail component too, that too is behaving as SHKFacebook part.

Regards,
Ishan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having this problem because you create ViewController in a wrong way.

Your `vc` doesn't know about your current orientation because you don't show it as a modal nor you added it to the navigation stack.

Probably, there is a much better way like you can use your application root controller.

You can probably get the right controller like this:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

or like this:

```
[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navController];
```

Depends on what you have in your AppDelegate (because of cocos2d templates)

So then do `[[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:vc];` and everything will be ok. By the way, i didn't find the method `setCurrentView` in `SHK` maybe because of versions, but if you have to set some view to SHK just use `vc.view` or application's window. Don't do anything to your GLView.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply, In the template, ViewController is being added as a subview to the window, have tried adding the viewController (From the app delegate), But the application is crashing. Also When i am adding the view controller,(As in the code in my first post), and then commenting out the SHK part (everything below the line "[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:self.vc.view];"), The orientation of the view controller is landscape(Which is what is required, verified by setting the background color of view,checking the frame/bounds). Any other thing i might be missing.

Comment: just try to use a controller from AppDelegate. If you have a crash there can you post your code, so maybe i can help you there. But i definitely think that you should use the existed root controller.

Comment: Crash was because of another issue. Thanks for the reply, appreciate  the help.